# Countability as bijective correspondence

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

I understand some set $X$ is countable if one can define a bijection between it and the set of natural numbers. In notation, is $f:X\rightarrow\Bbb{N}$ permissible, or must one write $f:\Bbb{N}\rightarrow X$? Or does this not matter? I find the latter notation more intuitive.

Comment: For a bijection, it doesn't matter. You just take the inverse mapping (which exists and is always unique).

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't matter because the assertions

1. there is a bijection $f\colon X\longrightarrow\mathbb N$;
2. there is a bijection $f\colon\mathbb N\longrightarrow X$

are equivalent. If each one of them holds for a certain map $f$, then the other one will hold for the map $f^{-1}$.

Answer (score 0):

If we define a relation on sets like $ A£B $ iff there is a bijection from set A to B, then this would be a equivalence relation on sets.

So there would be no difference on $ A£B $ and $ B£A $.